# Is there any way to know when I will receive my UK visa?

Tags: visas, uk, application-status

On May 9, I applied from Rome using the UK visa center. Two months have passed, and I have not been given any decision on my application. I submitted my visa request on the basis of my husband's Italian passport. It's been 70 days without any response. Is there any way to know when I will receive my visa?

Here's what the status screen shows:

[image]

Comment: Did you apply for an EEA family permit?

Comment: You should look into freedom of movement regulations. You should also have indicated when you applied for the visa that you were doing this with your freedom of movement rights. You don't even need a visa, but that can be tricky - this article explains more : https://eumovement.wordpress.com/2010/08/04/no-visa-but-still-want-to-travel/

Answer (score 2):

> **Is there any way to know when I will receive my visa?**

You can get information about current UK visa processing times at

https://www.gov.uk/visa-processing-times

It depends on where you apply, the type of visa and duration of visa.

Comment: +1, v nice. especially grateful for the link